# Predicate logic: Natural deduction: Introducing universal quantifier

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

For my logic class I am proving the following by natural deduction:
    ∃x∃yPxy ⊢ ∃y∃xPxy

It is done [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXfj0.png). (I am not yet allowed to embed images).
Please note the usage of an operator is indicated with an G.

However, my question is in the universal quantifier. I know that the deduction
    ∃x∃yPxy ⊢ ∀y∀xPxy
is wrong, I just can't figure out why [the "proof" for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRQiL.png) doesn't hold. Can anyone explain this further?

**Edit**: I figured out it is due to the a and b terms being substituted also being in the assumption block. I am still a bit iffy to what this exactly means, but I will figure this out. No further answers needed.

Comment: Consider the simple case with one quantifier: from $\exists x Px$ we derive $Pa$, but there is no reason to assume that, from the fact that $a$ is "a $P$", then every objcetc must be "a $P$".

Comment: This invalid step is blocked by the proviso of the [$\forall$-intro rule](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the additional info, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the a and b terms being substituted on line 4 and 5 are still in assumption, as shown on line 3. Only if this assumption has been proven, the universal quantifier can be introduced (I think).

Comment: Correct: $Pab$ is an assumption (following the double $\exists$-elim) and the prpviso of the $\forall$-intro rule does not allow us to "generalize" a variable that is free in an assupmtion.